How to use JsonStringEnumConverter in a JsonSerializerContext
The code below outputs:
{
  "ticket_state": 0
}

How can I add a JsonStringEnumConverter where the naming policy is JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseLower? I want the output to be:
{
  "ticket_state": "in_progress"
}

Code:
Ticket ticket = new Ticket()
{
    State = TicketState.InProgress
};

string serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(ticket, JsonContext.Default.Ticket);

Console.WriteLine(serialized);

public class Ticket
{
    [JsonPropertyName("ticket_state")]
    public TicketState State { get; set; }
}

public enum TicketState
{
    InProgress, WaitingOnCustomer, Resolved
}

[JsonSourceGenerationOptions(WriteIndented = true)]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(Ticket))]
internal partial class JsonContext : JsonSerializerContext
{

}


You can use the JsonConverter and specify JsonStringEnumConverter. But if you want to use the none default naming policy, I think you need to create your own type like this:
Ticket ticket = new Ticket()
{
    State = TicketState.InProgress
};

string serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(ticket, JsonContext.Default.Ticket);

Console.WriteLine(serialized);

public class Ticket
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumSnakeCaseLowerConverter<TicketState>))]
    [JsonPropertyName("ticket_state")]
    public TicketState State { get; set; }
}

public enum TicketState
{
    InProgress, WaitingOnCustomer, Resolved
}

[JsonSourceGenerationOptions(WriteIndented = true)]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(Ticket))]
internal partial class JsonContext : JsonSerializerContext
{
    
}

public class JsonStringEnumSnakeCaseLowerConverter<TEnum> : JsonStringEnumConverter<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    public JsonStringEnumSnakeCaseLowerConverter()
        : base(JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseLower, false)
    {

    }
}

